# How I can reslove FullScreenMenu.show error

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't know why I can't is this method

I'm beginner in flutter

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you include as Code-snippet and more about the Widget you are using

Answer (score 0):

`FullScreenMenu.show(` is a void method, so it cant be use on `child` which accept `Widget`. You use a button to show menu like

```dart
InkWell(
  child: Text("show Menu"),
  onTap: () {
    FullScreenMenu.show(
      context,
      items: [
        Image.asset('assets/image.png'),
        FSMenuItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit, color: Colors.white),
            text: Text('Make colder'),
            gradient: orangeGradient,
            onTap: () => print('Cool package check')),
        FSMenuItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.wb_sunny, color: Colors.white),
          text: Text('Make hotter'),
          gradient: blueGradient,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }),
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [full_screen_menu](https://pub.dev/packages/full_screen_menu)

Comment: thanks, how i can showing the menu in home page without button or text

Comment: are you trying to show dialog when this page open?

Comment: no i don't know how do it

Comment: what are you to do ?

Comment: i want a menu in my home page like iconbutton

Comment: Sorry I cant understand you, it would be easier if you can include a gif. also you may want IconButton WIdget to show this dialog

Comment: i slove my problem thanks